# Why React re-render third times when dependencies of useEffect is object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

result of below code is ([you can check it in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-72p6vj?file=/src/index.js:0-500))

```
start 

=useEffect= 

start 

=useEffect= 

start
```

I know the second render is caused by the change of setState (2 -> 3)

and in the second lifecycle, it can enter useEffect due to the change of object v1.key1

but what happened in the third render? why does it have a third render? (p.s. I've tried strict mode. the same problem!)

`

```
function App() {
  console.log("start");
  const v1 = { key1: { key2: 2 } };
  const [tryone, setTryone] = useState(2);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("=useEffect=");
    setTryone(3);
  }, [v1.key1]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

`

I think i expected result is like that

```
start 

=useEffect= 

start 

=useEffect=
```

Comment: that's because v1 is re-created on every re-render and setTryone causes a re-render. Probably, you want v1 to be state (useState) or a ref (useRef)

Comment: I know v1 is different for every render. but what triggers the third render?

Comment: yes, because use effect is modifed on every re-render. Check your useEffect. v1.key1 is a dependency so useEffect will be called every time v1.key1 is updated/modifed and v1 is always re-created on every re-render. If you don't want this behavior you should use useState because state will be the same on every re-render unless you modify it explicitelly

Comment: I totally understand v1 is different in each lifecycle, but my problem is why it trigger rerender in the useEffect in the second round lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Objects with the same contents aren't equal to each other. For another example outside of React:

```js
let outerObj;
const Component = () => {
  const obj = {};
  if (outerObj) {
    // Second execution
    console.log(outerObj === obj);
  } else {
    // First execution
    outerObj = obj;
  }
};
Component();
Component();
```

Your `App` is called twice, and each time it's called, the `const v1 = { key1: { key2: 2 } };` creates a new object - just like the snippet above runs `const obj = {}` twice, creating an object that isn't equal to the one generated in the prior call.

Your `v1.key1` changes every render, so

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("=useEffect=");
    setTryone(3);
  }, [v1.key1]);
```

may as well be

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("=useEffect=");
    setTryone(3);
  });
```

which runs the effect every render. After the change from 2 to 3, there's a rerender, so the effect runs again.

You need to create a stable reference for `v1` somehow - use `useMemo`, `useState`, or `useRef`.

```js
function App() {
  console.log("start");
  const v1 = React.useMemo(() => ({ key1: { key2: 2 } }), []);
  const [tryone, setTryone] = React.useState(2);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("=useEffect=");
    setTryone(3);
  }, [v1.key1]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: yes, because the object change, it enters useEffect in the second render.

but what triggers the third render?

Comment: Because the second render's effect calls the state setter, so the component re-renders.

Comment: in the second lifecycle. tryone is 3 and setTryone(3) in useEffect.  "3-> 3" triggers third rerender?

Comment: v1 is a different element. yes, 3==3 but v1 != v1 on every re-render, so, v1.key1 != v1.key1

Comment: I don't think different v1 will trigger rerender, it just means it can trigger useEffect.   If  different v1 really trigger rerender, the lifestyle will repeat infinitely.( But my example just repeats three times.)